# Extract data from WeatherData as a list of associations

Tags: function-construction, data

Given weather data for 2013 and 2014 as follows:

```
t = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
    WeatherData["California", "MeanTemperature", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Day"}] 
    "Values"]];
```

how can I get the average temperature for each day during 2 years as a list of associations, for example:

> ```
> January 1 -> 12
>  ...
>  December 31 -> -20
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me your command doesn't run. I run:

```
t = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
    WeatherData[
      "California", 
      "MeanTemperature", 
      {{2013, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Day"}
    ]["Values"]];
```

This contains all temperature quantities.

A list of dates in your period is easily constructed by

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2013, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}]]
```

so the association array you're looking for can be obtained from

```
AssociationThread[
    DateRange[DateObject[{2013, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}]] -> t
];
```

**edit**

In fact, a neater way to achieve this is:

```
t = WeatherData["California", "MeanTemperature", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 1}, "Day"}];
Association[Rule @@@ MapAt[DateObject, t["Path"], {All, 1}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if one of the years has February 29, how can that be considered for the calculation?

Comment: If the year is a leap year, like 2012, February 29 will be included in `DateRange[{2012, 1, 1}, {2012, 12, 31}]` automatically. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Actually no, can I explain the question to you via pm?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how that works :p

Comment: Could you add me on Skype - megibyan ?

Comment: You can create your own chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) (Mike might need >10 rep to be able to participate). But @Mike if there is a problem with this answer you should make an effort to explain that here so that future visitors can see it. Welcome to MMA.SE.